# Different BoundaryStyle for different sides of a RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, graphics3d, regions

How can one Define a function in the RegionPlot that gives different BoundaryStyle for different sides? I mean

```
RegionPlot[func[x,y]>=0.5,{x,0,750},{y,0,750},BoudaryStyle->Function[something]]
```

Where `Function[something]` gives different BoundaryStyles based on the position of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to

1. Post-process `RegionPlot` output to extract the coordinates of line primitives.
2. Construct a `BSplineFunction` for each line using the extracted coordinates.
3. Use the list of constructed functions to create a list of `ParametricPlot`s each with the desired color function.
4. Combine the original `RegionPlot` and constructed `ParametricPlot`s using `Show`.

Example:

```
rp = RegionPlot[1 <= x^2 + y <= 2 || 3 <= x^2 + y <= 4 || 1 <= x^2 + (y + 2)^2 <= 2, 
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 60, ImageSize -> Medium];
bsFs = Cases[Normal[rp], Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All];
colorfuncs = {ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][#2] &, ColorData["SolarColors"][#] &, 
  ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &, GrayLevel[# + #2] &};
parametricplots = ParametricPlot[ #[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01], 
   ColorFunction -> #2] & @@@ Transpose[{bsFs, colorfuncs}];
Row[{rp, Show[rp, parametricplots]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by post-processing the RegionPlot output. I am assuming that the only line primitives are the region edges and I replace them with lots of single segment lines, individually styled. We need to do Normal to ensure that we have easy access to the line coordinates. For example this will set the edge graylevel to the x coordinate value...

`lineStyle[expr_, fn_] := expr /. Line[data_List] :> Map[{fn[#[[1]]], Line[#]} &,    Partition[data, 2, 1]]`

`lineStyle[Normal[RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]], GrayLevel[#[[1]]/2] &]`